# Localizing Crashlytics Beta email Notifications

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric, email-notifications, crashlytics-beta

I am using Crashlytics Beta for iOS Build Distribution.I want to send the email notification in Japanese instead of English.Is there any way to Customize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Currently, there isn't a way to customize the invite notifications into other languages. However, you can set the release notes in whatever language you want and that would be displayed in the update emails you're testers receive.